# How to display review stars in angular5 view using font-awesome

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have the review stars value in the database. Example **2.5** for an item.
I want to display this in the template using font-awesome.

```
<ul class="rating inline-ul">
    <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
</ul>
```

What will be the way to display the stars in accordance with the review value?

I used *ngIf, but that seems like overkill with a lot code and possibly how to represent the half stars.

```
 <ul class="rating inline-ul" *ngIf="2.5">
        <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star amber-half"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: How do you store the rating? Is it a property of your component class?

Comment: Yes it's a property. ```this.starValue = 2.5```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the code snippets:

StackBlitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbmtmv

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value = 2.5; //addition of .5
  starList: string[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    let i=1;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      if(i<= this.value) {
        this.starList.push("fas fa-star");
      } else if(i <= this.value+0.5) {
        this.starList.push("fas fa-star-half");
      } else {
        this.starList.push("far fa-star");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<span *ngFor="let star of starList">
  <i class="{{star}}"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following. Add a new `Arr` property to your class

```
export class YourComponent {
  Arr = Array;
}
```

Then, in your html:

```
<ul class="rating inline-ul">
        <li  *ngFor="let i of Arr(Math.floor(starValue)).fill(1)"><i class="fa fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
        <li *ngIf="starValue % 1 === 0"><i class="fa fa-star amber-half"></i></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: ```ERROR RangeError: Invalid array length``` with .5 numbers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've modified the answer to account for that

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Commercial Suicide, it was the solution I was looking for.

To completely satisfy my need, I did an improvement, to also show the "empty" stars. I added else inside *ngIF

```
*ngIf="starValue >= i + 0.5; else emptyStar"
```

and added this block that will show the "empty" stars

```
<ng-template #emptyStar>
  <i class="far fa-star"></i>
</ng-template>
```

In index.html, i changed the font awesome version to v5.1.0 to support classes fas (solid) and far (regular)

Complete code here 
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2syu5)

Answer (score 1):

You can create items dynamically via `*ngFor` and give them class (dynamically too) via `ngClass`, based on `starValue` value:

```
<ul class="rating inline-ul">
  <li *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index">
    <i class="fa" *ngIf="starValue >= i + 0.5" [ngClass]="{'fa-star-half': starValue >= i + 0.5 && starValue < i + 1, 'fa-star': starValue >= i + 1}"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And don't forget to initialize the array in the component, which `length` will be equal to the number of stars (doesn't matter, half-filled, filled or empty):

```
public stars: any[] = new Array(5);
```

And here is the [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etfhwz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) (I have changed some classes to render the output properly). Here you can play around and configure the behavior as you want.

Comment: How about showing the complete five empty stars (fa fa-star-o), that are then filled.