# How to write css classes with *ngFor in template

Tags: angular

I am trying to write the following in angular4 *ngFor 
I want something like :
  [image]

```
      public stars: any[] = new Array(5);

        <ul class="rating inline-ul">
          <li *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index">
            <i class="fa" *ngIf="starValue >= i + 0.5" 
            [ngClass]="{'fa-star-half-o amber-text': starValue >= i + 0.5 
            && starValue < i + 1, 'fa-star amber-text': starValue >= i + 1}">
           </i>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Unfortunately the above code gives me this :

[image]

How can I achieve this, *ngFor?

Comment: Can you refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582789/how-to-display-review-stars-in-angular5-view-using-font-awesome/49583014#49583014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything right except `else` part of `*ngIf`.

```
<div class="rating inline-ul">
 <span *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index">
  <i class="fa" *ngIf="starValue >= i + 0.5; else star" [ngClass]="{
    'fa-star-half-o amber-text': starValue >= i + 0.5 && starValue < i + 1, 
    'fa-star amber-text': starValue >= i + 1
  }">
  </i>
  <!-- else part -->
  <ng-template #star>
      <i class="far fa-star"></i>
  </ng-template>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following will be right fit:

```
<ul class="rating inline-ul">
  <li *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index">
    <i   
    [class.fas]="i+0.5 < starValue || i+0.5 == starValue" 
    [class.far]="i > starValue"  
    [class.fa-star]="i+0.5 < starValue || i > starValue"  
    [class.fa-star-half]="i+.5 == starValue" >
    </i>
    <span *ngIf="i+.5 < starValue">fas fa-star</span>
    <span *ngIf="i+.5 == starValue">fas fa-star-half</span>
    <span *ngIf="i > starValue">far fa-star</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can find the implementation from following StackBlitz URL: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbmtmv

Comment: I see that. Thanks. But ```this.value``` is only available in the *ngFor not in the component class!

Comment: The values available in view (template) are obtained from the component itself. Hence this.value must be accessible in the component.

Comment: @PareshLomate definitely, but I find no need of another subscribe method in the component class just for this value.